# How to install civix and build an extension in drupal

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, civicrm-buildkit, civix

Please I don't know how to install civix and build an extension using civicrm. I
already installed drupal and civicrm module. but I have no clue how to write an extension or how to run anything here. I am totally new to it.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Developer Guide here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/ as a start.

If at all possible I would recommend trying to find an expert near you who would be able to give you a developer training. You would have to pay for it but it will probably save you a lot of exploration time :-)

Answer (score -1):

Download Buildkit from github.
Then set environment variable.

Set civicrm.setting.php in evvironment variable (C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\default\civicrm.setting.php)

Then goto the directory -> {I am using xampp -> C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\default\files\civicrm\ext ).

Open your cmd (right shift + right click) then type 
civix civicrm:ping

Comment: You don't need the entire buildkit just to get Civix which can be downloaded as a self-contained PHAR.

Comment: then follow the instruction of civix and if you get any problem then post again. We Shall help